# What effect does a journal having multiple ISSN codes have on reporting citations?

Tags: publications, publishers, online-publication

Recently, I submitted a paper into a general whose name also appears on the SCIE list of web of science. My paper got accepted. The journal actually has two ISSN numbers (one for print and the other for online). Only one ISSN (print) appears on the web of science list. I want to know what does it mean? Will my paper be included in print version or not? (The journal did not ask about this choice at any stage of the whole process.) If it is not included in the print version then can I write the impact factor of the journal next to the title of my article on my personal website?

I will be very thankful for clarifying my confusion.

Comment: I am confused. According to [ISSN web page](http://www.issn.org/understanding-the-issn/what-is-an-issn/): _An ISSN (International Standard Serial Number) identifies all continuing resources, irrespective of their medium (print or electronic)_

Comment: What are the ISSNs you are looking at? This would make it easier for others to troubleshoot/answer.

Comment: I have encountered with this problem. I think it’s a kind of fraud. If a journal have two ISSN, both of them must be same and not different!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

From what I can understand, currently active journals that are published both online and in print will have both a p-ISSN and an e-ISSN. This means that your paper (which will be published in both channels) will be attached to both ISSNs. See Wikipedia:

> When a serial with the same content is published in more than one media type, a different ISSN is assigned to each media type. For example, many serials are published both in print and electronic media. The ISSN system refers to these types as print ISSN (p-ISSN) and electronic ISSN (e-ISSN), respectively.[citation needed] Conversely, as defined in ISO 3297:2007, every serial in the ISSN system is also assigned a linking ISSN (ISSN-L), typically the same as the ISSN assigned to the serial in its first published medium, which links together all ISSNs assigned to the serial in every medium.[4]

ISSNs of different types for the same journal are connected through ISSN linking (ISSN-L). A file of ISSN links can also be downloaded from the [ISSN website](http://www.issn.org/services/online-services/access-to-issn-l-table/), to check whether specific ISSNs are really linked. You can also read about ISSN linking at wikipedia: [Wikipedia: International Standard Serial Number#Linking_ISSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number#Linking_ISSN).

Comment: Do you happen to know any journal which has both p-ISSN and e-ISSN assigned to it?

Comment: I think most current scientific journals have both. See e.g. [Journal of Ecology](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1365-2745), which shows "Online ISSN: 1365-2745" (i.e. e-ISSN) on their website, while the ISSN shown at Clarivate Journal Citations Reports (previously Thomson-Reuters) is  0022-0477, which is the print-ISSN.

Comment: Do you think there will be journals that publish your paper only in the online version (which is not indexed in known databases like scopus..) and leave the print version only for high end recommended papers?